# finding value of definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions

Does the following definite integral exist

[image: png]

here $\alpha > 0$ and $n$ is positive integer.

Comment: Looks to me that taking the parentheses for a variable substitution simplifies the expression.

Comment: Can I ask the source of that integral? Is just curiosity?

Comment: I think this integral is finite only when $\alpha \in (0,1)$.